# technical localization

Tags: android, localization

Not picking up values from `values-de-rCH/strings.xml` but from `values-de/strings.xml`.

My device locale is set to `de-CH` and the same is confirmed when I debug the code at some place for loading a JSON based URL config file for other purposes...

Comment: What region is CH? When you create the `strings.xml` in the directory, does a flag appear next to the file in Android Studio?

Comment: Akash, let me know in which os level you are running the app? Actully it's depending in your device os

Comment: @StuStirling `What region is CH?` Switzerland. Although I would use ***standard*** GERMAN, for Swisse, Austria and Liechenstein. They all would understand the **mother language** of which **they speak just a dialect**.

Comment: @StuStirling not sure of the flag you are talking about, but i wanted to ask that some of the strings.xml show up my build variant as well in the form of (de, <build_variant_name>), when looking at the res folder structure in Studio, while others don't. Is that of any concern here that could possibly point out to something i m missing...?

Comment: @RashpalSingh the device OS version number is 7.0

Comment: When I have added a strings file for specific languages and have incorrectly named them, the strings.xml file doesn't have the country's flag icon next to it. However when I name it correctly the icon shows next to it. My thoughts are the region.and language combination you want isn't supported
L

Comment: I can't see any such flag. Can u attach a screenshot for the same here, iff possible? As far as the incorrect naming convention is considered, i simply some of the online articles to add a new locale, all which specifiy the same way of doing so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://blog.egorand.me/a-curious-case-of-multiple-locales/

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code

According to the above 2 links, it asked me to mention my new region-specific locales e.g de-rCH, to the resConfigs, or set the resConfigs itself as auto. In both cases, it worked for me. I was kind of stuck in this for almost over a week now.
Thanks for your help guys...

Answer (score 0):

Android has different resolution scheme for string file prior to 7.0 and after.
You can find the reference at Android developer website 
[Language and locale resolution](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/multilingual-support) .

Also if your app support different language (not same language but different country) it is better to create folder with language code only. e.g. **values-de**.

For detail description of naming directories explained at [Support different languages and cultures](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages).

Comment: Meanwhile i look into the links you shared, I actually need to have both values-de/strings.xml & values-de-rCH/strings.xml...

Comment: So you have different strings for Switzerland(CH) locale than other German locale?

Comment: yes, kind of like the default de locale for regions not being supported by my app...

Comment: i also tried renaming my folder from values-de-rCH to values-b+de+756 according to the link you shared for 7.0, but still no luck...